How can I let a user know the newly created token address?
I have a smart contract that acts as a factory to create new ERC-20 tokens. A user can creates tokens through my website.
When a user sends a transaction and interacts with my create function, how can I let the user know the newly created token address?
I figured subscribing to a token created event was the best method but this could in theory receive plenty of other newly created tokens until it finally finds one created by the logged in user. This seems inefficient.
Any ideas or insights?

Have you looked at using create2 to determine the address and returning it from the function directly?
